# Dojo filteringselect STRUTS application

Tags: java, javascript, struts, dojo

I am using DOJO UI framework for a STRUTS application. I need to find a way to invalidate the `filteringselect` item. The `invalidMessage` is getting set however the error icon does not show because all values in the list including the selected one are indeed valid items of the list.

I noticed if i modify the `displayValue` in the `filteringselect` i am able to see the error icon and the `invalidMessage`. Is there a way to show the error icon and the `invalidMessage` without having to modifying the `displayValue` to an invalid value from the list?

This validation is required since the user could select a valid option but it can be an invalid option based on the action being preformed by the user (custom validation)

Here is the code:

**HTML Struts and DOJO filteringselect**

```
<s:select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect"
   id="genderId" name=mygenderId" title="(7). Gender"
   headerKey="0" headerValue="Select Your Gender" list="genderList"
   listKey="id" missingMessage="Please Select Your Gender" required="true"
   invalidMessage="Invalid Gender Type !"
   listValue="genderName" style="width: 25em;" />
```

**Server Side Validation**

This does not work i cannot set a new invalidMessage.

```
 var myWidgetValue = 'Invalid option please try again !';
 var myWidget = dijit.byId("genderId");
 myWidget.validator = function () {                                       
    console.log('Setting '+widgetName + " : "+myWidgetValue);
    this.set("invalidMessage", myWidgetValue);
 };

 myWidget._hasBeenBlurred = true;
 myWidget.validate();
```

Comment: Is `myWidget` defined before you attempt to override its `validator()` function? If it is, does it have a `missingMessage` property? It sounds like something isn't defined correctly, but it's hard to tell without knowing if/where an error occurs in your code.

Comment: @DesertIvy myWidget is defined before an attempt is made to override the validator and yes in the coide above it has a missingMessage defined. I think the reason the validator isn't showing the red exclamation mark is the value selected in the filteringselect option is valid so it cannot show the error icon. There for i need a way to show the icon regardless of the selected value. I actually changed the selected text to a value that does not exist and the invalidMessage set shows. I may need to restructure my question.